# Please explain `sudo ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu nvidia autoinstall`?

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia, ubuntu-drivers

I would like to install the Nvidia driver using the command-line.

Simply installing the driver package does not *activate* it in the Additional Drivers tab of Software & Updates (even though the package is installed).

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440
```

I came across the command...

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu autoinstall nvidia
```

*Before* I execute this, I would like to understand what it will do...

1. Does it do anything different than `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440` or `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440`?
2. Will it configure and activate the driver after installation?
3. Which version of the driver will this command install, or do I have to specify a version by appending it, as follows?

   ```
    sudo ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu autoinstall nvidia:440
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up trying this command.

`sudo ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu nvidia autoinstall`

As far as I can tell, it does the same thing as installing the the latest tested proprietary graphics driver from the Additional Drivers tab.